# Android camera tutorial - galleryaddpic not working

Tags: java, android, camera

I'm following the *Taking Photos Simply* [Android developers guide](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html) 
Everything seems to be working correctly apart from saving the picture to gallery.

All the code is taken from the guide and looks like this:

I have a floating action button that launches the camera intent

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            dispatchTakePictureIntent();


        }
    });



 private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created

        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "packagename.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);

        }
    }

}
```

---

```
   @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        setPic();
        galleryAddPic();
    }
}
```

---

```
  private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_testimage" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

---

```
 private void galleryAddPic() {
    Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    File f = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
    Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
    this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
}
```

Manifest:

```
<!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities= "packagename.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>


</application>
```

file_paths.xml:

```
 <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/packagename/files/Pictures" />
```

Comment: "Everything seems to be working correctly apart from saving the picture to gallery" -- please edit your question and explain, **in detail**, what this means.

Comment: For Android 6+ Marshmallow, you need Runtime permission.

Comment: Does the image show in your folder and not in your gallery?

Comment: The image doesn't show up anywhere besides as a thumbnail in my imageview- as far as I can tell.

Comment: try to log or a toast in `if (photoFile != null)` to see if the file was created.

Comment: Well the toast shows up as soon as the camera launches and not when the picture is taken.

Comment: ohh sorry I meant to say in `if` statement inside `onActivityResult`

Comment: By checking if mCurrentPhotoPath != null, I can see that it is not null. Good to know but unsure where to go from here

Comment: @smuvv What are your android min and max sdk versions? And, did you ask for `storage-permission` inside `java` file?

Comment: @smuvv - did u get any solution or workaround for this problem? I am running into exactly same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have requested and/or have storage permissions

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), file.getAbsolutePath(), file.getName()/*file name*/, file.getName()/*description*/);
```

Comment: I have storage permission, and it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Once, try with this `file_path.xml` file. I stumbled into the same problem some while ago and I had to replace the `path` attribute of `external-file-path` tag to `.` to fix it. Since, you are calling `getExternalFileDir()` method, you need to specify path with `external-files-path` I guess.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-files-path
    name="my_images"
    path="." />
</paths>
```

With this xml, you would share the root directory which would work **sub-directory name inside that root directory**. If you want to specify the exact sub-directory, you need to supply `path` attribute as below:
`path="Android/data/<com.example.package.name>/files/Pictures"` replacing `com.example.package.name` with exact **package name** of your application.